# Forcing change of option in required select

Tags: javascript, forms

I have a select where the first option is a placeholder.
It has disabled, hidden, selected attributes.
Select is set as required.
How to prevent users from submitting the form with the first option checked by default?
Thanks

```
<select id="pick-option" required>
  <option disabled hidden selected>choose:</option>
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
<select>
```

Comment: None of those options have `value` attributes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set `value=""` on the default option.

Check out this example: https://codepen.io/dusanjovanov92/pen/rNZqVZw

Comment: what a beautiful, simple solution, thanks very much